# Offset Google markers at the same address

Tags: google-maps-api, markers

What can I incorporate into my current code below to offset markers, as markers at the same address don't show.

Here's example http://www.mediwales.com/mapping/test

UPDATE:
I've changed the way the map works by running it from a database.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var cluster = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4788, -3.9551),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);
        }
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add your 'get_posts(array' to the var markers for the MarkerCluster Manager to build the dynamic marker.

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
var options = {
  'zoom': 13,
  'center': center,
  'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
var markers = [...]; // Create the markers you want to add and collect them into a array.
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Source:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

V3 ClusterMarker Reference
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

Comment: I've changed the way the map generates (i.e from a database) but obviously the same problem still exists. I've updated my question with the new code.

Comment: Once you've obtained an array of your markers (it's not important how they are fetched) then pass them to the marker clusterer, as in the last line of code above.

Comment: MarkerClusterer won't solve this issue, because MarkerClusterer is intended for Markers that don't share the same lat/long.